# How to count unread messages in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to get a simple count of unread messages in a folder, but I'd like to just get a count without having to retrieve any of the message detail.

The closest I've got is something like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=isRead ne true&$count=true&$select=id&top=1
```

Notice that I'm including `$select=id` here, but I don't really want that - I'm just looking for a simple count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is closer to what I need:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/mailFolders/Inbox
```

This gives some basic folder information for that folder, including the unreadItemCount.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('{user}')/mailFolders/$entity",
    "id": "AAMkADQwNDkzY2MwLWRkODMtNDdkYS05MjNmLWI0YTA4OTNlN2U1ZgAuAAAAAABpELO9F64CS6YLKzHVeiwoAQDXOQANV1mvRZBdzyuZRD-5AAAAAAEMAAA=",
    "displayName": "Inbox",
    "parentFolderId": "AAMkADQwNDkzY2MwLWRkODMtNDdkYS05MjNmLWI0YTA4OTNlN2U1ZgAuAAAAAABpELO9F64CS6YLKzHVeiwoAQDXOQANV1mvRZBdzyuZRG-5AAAAAAEIAAA=",
    "childFolderCount": 0,
    "unreadItemCount": 1,
    "totalItemCount": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get only the unread item count of your Inbox (or any other folder, for that matter), you can use this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox?$select=unreadItemCount
```

This will return:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('{user}')/mailFolders/$entity",
    "id": "AAMkADQwNDkzY2MwLWRkODMtNDdkYS05MjNmLWI0YTA4OTNlN2U1ZgAuAAAAAABpELO9F64CS6YLKzHVeiwoAQDXOQANV1mvRZBdzyuZRD-5AAAAAAEMAAA=",
    "unreadItemCount": 19
}
```